# How to check if two functions are equal?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to keep a list of unique functions. So, `listeners` below should have a length of 1

```
final listeners = <VoidCallback>[];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  void listener() => setState(() {});
  if (!listeners.contains(listener)) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }
}
```

But `contains` is returning false, so the same closure is added 5x. I tried testing with `listener.hashCode` but each hash was unique, so `listeners.length` was 5.

Is it possible to test for the same function?

If I move the function outsize

```
final listeners = <VoidCallback>[];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  void listener() => setState(() {});
  if (!listeners.contains(listener)) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }
}
```

Then `listeners.length` is 1, but I'm writing a library and need to accommodate the first use case.

Comment: If the `hashCode`s are different, on what basis are you determining they are the same function?

Comment: This make no sense. Each closure is unique, so all of them will be added, which is the correct behaviour. What is the real problem your are trying to solve? Your question seems to be about a specific solution you have in mind.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I clearly don't understand `hashCode`. Why does `void listener() => setState(() {});` generate a unique `hashCode` for each iteration of the loop? Isn't it the same function?

Comment: It's not the same function, as you are re-declaring it on every iteration. Declare it before the loop, then it will be the same object.

Comment: Closures cannot compare equal to each other; they implicitly have different calling environments (i.e., they have access to different sets of local variables).  A sufficiently sophisticated compiler perhaps could determine that `() {}` does not depend on any variables local to where it's declared and automatically canonicalize it, but that currently isn't done. (Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1048.) For now, if you really need to compare `Function` objects, I'd suggest always requiring named functions/methods.